# How to set multiple cookies with expires-attribute in Apigee?

Tags: javascript, cookies, apigee

When setting multiple cookies via Apigee's response.header.Set-Cookie array, and using the Expires attribute (because that's the only reliable option for IE) in the `Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT` format, Apigee will consider the comma as some kind of cookie separator and effectively cut everything after the comma. It will however work if only the last cookie comes with an Expires attribute.

Any idea on how this can be solved for multiple cookies?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I came across [an alternate date format](https://github.com/pillarjs/cookies/issues/59#issuecomment-119220732) that does not include a comma. It is generated by ANSI C's `asctime` format. When setting the expires attribute with this date format, it works with more than one cookie.

Since I couldn't find any `asctime` JavaScript port on the web (which is what Apigee can use easily), here's one I quickly compiled:

```
function asctime(d) {
    var weekdays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

    return weekdays[d.getDay()] +
    " " + months[d.getMonth()] +
    (d.getDate() < 10 ? "  " : " ") + d.getDate() +
    (d.getHours() < 10 ? " 0" : " ") + d.getHours() +
    (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? ":0" : ":") + d.getMinutes() +
    (d.getSeconds() < 10 ? ":0" : ":") + d.getSeconds() +
    " " + d.getFullYear();
}
```